# Form Submit Click Not working in IE 10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, alertify

I am using [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) for alert generation in my website.
In the working of website there is this case in which a user can click on a name from the online list of people and there will a notification sent to that person.

While the request notification is shown at the other end there is a accept button on it.Its a form actually,in which when a user click on "Start" a new tab will be open with few parameters send as POST method.

My code for Alertify.js is :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

alertify.log("<?php echo $row['from']." want to talk to You !! <br> "?><div><form  action='chatIndex.php' method='POST' target='_blank'><input type='hidden' name='not_no' value='<?php echo $row['no']?>'><input type='hidden' name='not_from' value='<?php echo $row['from']?>'><input type='submit' style='float:left' value='Start' /></div>");

</script>
```

This is working fine in Chrome,Firefox but not working in IE 10.
I also have used these meta tag for proper working of Jquery in IE 10

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" >
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

Comment: Why are you setting X-UA meta tags for IE9 regarding page rendering when the question is about IE10? `content="IE=10"`, `content="IE=EmulateIE10"` instead!

Comment: yeah about that.. i actually searched it over internet and used it and it happens to work well !!

Answer (score 0):

Add this too (forgot to add IE=10):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />
```